# NGINX rewriting url simple

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to do a rewrite urol very simple with nginx but it doesn't work.

I wand to redirect all the page www.domain.com/test/* in www.domain.com/test/

I try that but wihtout success : 
rewrite ^/test/* http://www.domain.com/test/ permanent;

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this rewrite `rewrite ^test/.+ /test/ permanent;`